# How to create a custom primary key using strings and date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an order table in sql server and I need for the order number primary key to be like this

`OR\20160202\01`

`OR` is just a string
`20160202` is the Date
`01` is sequence number for that day

for second Order record the same day it would be

`OR\20160202\02` and so on..

backlashes should also be included...

Whats the way to go about creating such a field in sql server (using version 2016)

EDIT: to add more context to what sequence number is, its just a way for this field composite or not to be unique. without a sequence number i would get duplicate records in DB because i could have many records the same day so date would remain the same thus it would be something like

`OR\20160202` for all rows for that particular day so it would be duplicate. Adding a "sequence" number helps solve this.

Comment: Don't just don't.  Formatted PK is problematic at best.

Comment: A better approach would be to create a unique index on the pieces of data that need to be unique across the record. Alternatively you can also create a composite primary key but I usually avoid this approach unless there is a good technical reason (not business case reason).

Comment: by the way, what is `sequence number for that day`? How do you determine this? Or is this data from an existing column in your table?

Comment: Ah the sequence number is just the first record for that date so every day it resets to 01. So esentially you are suggesting to create three columns?

Comment: If `OR` is also some piece of data that is captured on the record then that would probably be the best approach. Also I recommend capturing the date as a sql `date` object and not a string. This will help you later on when you have to write queries, lets say all records that fall on a date or between a set of dates. Not to mention there is validation built in, you could never add the date `2016-02-30` but this would be allowed if it were a string/varchar.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to not create such a column in SQL. You're effectively combining multiple pieces of data into the same column, which shouldn't happen in a relational database for many reasons. A column should hold one piece of data.

Instead, create a composite primary key across all of the necessary columns.

Comment: this fails to address how to create sequence for the day

Comment: That's a business process decision. If they need to have sequential order numbers for each day then the application should create that and it all depends on the business rules. If a customer creates 3 orders then the second one is deleted then does the third now become the second? This is beyond the scope of the database PK though.

Comment: That is a the business requirement. "Whats the way to go about creating such a field in sql server" is the stated question and this answer fails to address the sequence number.

Answer (score 0):

composite pk
order varchar(20)
orDate DateTime

```
select * 
     , row_number() over (partition by cast(orDate as Date) order by orDate) as seq  
from table
```

Will leave it to you on how to concatenate the data
That is presentation thing - don't make it a problem for the PK

Answer (score 0):

About "sequence number for that day" (department, year, country, ...).
Almost every time I discussed such a requirement with end users it turned out to be just misunderstanding of how shared database works, a vague attempt to repeat old (separate databases, EXCEL files or even paper work) tricks on shared database.
So i second Tom H and others, first try not to do it.

If nevertheless you must do it, for legal or other unnegotiatable reasons then i hope you are on 2012+. Create SEQUENCE for every day.

Answer (score 0):

Formatted PK is not a good idea.Composite key is a better approach.The combination of day as a date column and order number as a bigint column should be used.This helps in improving the query performance too.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore 'Date Dimension' table. Date Dimension is commonly used table in data warehousing. It stores all the days of the calendar(based on your choice of years) and numeric generated keys for these days. Check this post on date dimension. It talks about creating one in SQL SERVER.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/